# How to call a php function and return its result elsewhere

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Rookie PHP developer trying to implement my functions like so:

- call a php function from `<a>` with a parameter (this is my menu link)
- returns the php function output in a separate `<div>` (this is the content area)

I have already created my functions and all works well but I can't come to grip with the steps involved to implement it by calling it from the menu. My guess is that I need AJAX ?

any lead appreciated

Comment: this is exactly ajax. https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_php.asp you can find php examples

Comment: AJAX is not related. The term you are looking for is "API". APIs can be both synchronous and asynchronous.

Comment: It is however recommended to use Ajax (asynchronous), to provide a better user experience, as this allows for requests and data to be exchanged without changing the browser's location

Comment: *"My guess is that I need AJAX "* Some basic web searching into how ajax works and what it is used for would have answered that for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes ajax is the way to go.

Here is a tiny example using jQuery and ajax:

```
<a role="button" data-someAction="myAction">My action</a>
<div id="action_result"></div>

<!-- load jQuery libraries -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {

        $('a').click(function () {

            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'action.php',
                data: $(this).attr('data-someAction'),
                success: function (data) {

                    $('#action_result').html(data);

                }
            });

        });

    });
</script>
```

PHP

```
$code = <<<HERE
  function someAction() {
    echo 'awesome';
  }
HERE;

echo $code;
```

Answer (score 0):

To call it, you need to set an event handler to detect if the `a` has been clicked. i.e:

html:

```
<a href="something.php" id="link"></a>
```

js:

```
function handler(){
    console.log("Clicked!");
    somefunction();
}

document.getElementById("link").addEeventListener("click",handler);
```

jquery:

```
$("#link").click(function(event){
    //ajax here...
});
```

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_addeventlistener.asp